# Using the cordova file plugin no callback is called when creating a file

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I'm using `org.apache.cordova.file` plugin latest version, on IOS 8.1, i but when i try to create a file nothing happens:

```
getRootDirectory();

        function getRootDirectory() {
            console.log("getting root dir");
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, gotFS, fail);
        }

        function gotFS(fileSystem) {
            console.log('got fs', fileSystem);
            var fileName = "capb_logs.txt";
            var filePath = fileSystem.root.fullPath;

            if (filePath === '/') {filePath = '';}

            path = filePath + "/" + fileName;

            fileSystem.root.getFile(fileName, { create: true, exclusive: false }, gotFileEntry, fail);
        }

        function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
            console.log('gotFileEntry',fileEntry );
            fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
        }

        function gotFileWriter(writer) {
            console.log('gotFileWriter');
            writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
                emailHandler.sendEmailWithAttachments({
                    subject: 'CA Executive Playbook - Debug Logs',
                    body: 'Log file attached',
                    attachments: [{
                        filePath: path
                    }],
                });
            };

            var logs = log.getAllLogs(false);
            writer.write(logs);
        }

        function fail(error) {
            console.log('Failed to get file', error);
            util.showMessage('Error', 'There was a problem in opening an email client');
            de.reject(error);
        }
```

I get to the `gotFs` method, but when i call `fileSystem.root.getFile(fileName, { create: true, exclusive: false }, gotFileEntry, fail);` nothing happens, neither success nor fail callbacks are being called.

here is the filesystem object i get:

[image]